# "What's not to love?"

Tags: meaning, idioms

What do people really mean when they say "what's not to love"? Is there any context in particular to use this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a variation on the older phrase, "what's not to like". The question is rhetorical, it's a different way of saying that you can't think of a reason why anybody would not love/like X; there is nothing not to love/like about it. At least that's what the literal meaning is. Nowadays, the phrase is such a [cliché](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clich%C3%A9) that it's often used ironically, to mean the exact opposite thing.

The Phrase Finder provides [some background](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/whats-not-to-like.html):

> The earliest example of 'what's not to like?' that I've found in print is in Dorothy Kilgallen's review of the film *Charade* in the 'Voice of Broadway' column in the New York newspaper The Dunkirk Evening Observer, September 1963:
>
> "It has Audrey Hepburn, Cary Grant, Paris in living color, and a beautiful score by Henry Mancini. So what's not to like?"
>
> [...]
>
> The 'what's not to love?' spinoff variant started in 1974, as part of Volkswagen's advertising copy for a limited edition range of Beetle models that were styled on the *Love Bug* that featured in Disney's eponymous 1968 film.

It even has a picture of the said ad.

Answer (score 1):

It's a way of saying

"How can one not love ... ?"

or more precisely:

"What characteristic of ... can one dislike ?"

I think it's clearer under the form "what's not to love about ...". Such as for instance:

"What's not to love about this kid."

Answer (score 1):

The confusion may arise from the elided "there".

"What's not to love?" can be expanded as "What *is there* not to love *about [subject of discussion]*?" where the italicized words are the words left out of the original construction.

The speaker is asking the listener to list objections; usually, though, the statement is rhetorical.